# laravel undefined variable gaurd

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, middleware

Here is my code for creating middleware for routing, here i am using Auth::guard, so it is showing undefined variable guard, thanks in advance

```
 <?php
      namespace App\Http\Middleware;

      use Closure;


      class accesscontrol
      {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
         if (\Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->user_type == '5')  
         {      
                return $next($request);
         }  
          return redirect('/login');  
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Auth;**

Pass the variable, define  handle method like below:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{

 if (\Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->user_type == '5'){

    return $next($request);
  }

  return redirect('/login');

}
```

Comment: hi , $gaurd set to null , but it is not validating condition

Comment: So your previous problem is solved right ?  check the condition

Answer (score 2):

The statement

`use guard`

is incorrect.

Replace it with

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't want to use a custom guard at all, so just use `Auth::check()` or `auth()->check()` instead:

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->user_type == '5') {
    return $next($request);
}
```

If you want to use it, specify it:

```
Auth::guard('custom-guard-name')->check()
```

Comment: @vinod what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error or something?